# Wordpress get_the_terms for custom Taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

Within an archive page, I'm trying to show the a custom taxonomy (called location) along with each post title, category and tag. I can't get the 'get_the_terms' to work.

The post title, category and tag is working perfectly. The taxonomy doesn't work.

```
<div class="post-listing">
        <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
        <p><?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { echo $category->cat_name . ' '; } ?></p>
        <p><?php $tags = get_the_tags(); foreach($tags as $tag) { echo "$tag->name"; } ?></p>
        <p><?php $terms = get_the_terms( 'locations' ); foreach($terms as $term) { echo "$term->name"; } ?></p>
</div>
```

This is my functions.php code.

```
//hook into the init action and call create_locations_nonhierarchical_taxonomy when it fires
    add_action( 'init', 'create_locations_nonhierarchical_taxonomy', 0 );
    function create_locations_nonhierarchical_taxonomy() {
    // Labels part for the GUI
      $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Locations', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Location', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Locations' ),
        'popular_items' => __( 'Popular Locations' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Locations' ),
        'parent_item' => null,
        'parent_item_colon' => null,
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Location' ), 
        'update_item' => __( 'Update Location' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Location' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New Location Name' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate locations with commas' ),
        'add_or_remove_items' => __( 'Add or remove locations' ),
        'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Choose from the most used locations' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'Locations' ),
      ); 
    // Now register the non-hierarchical taxonomy like tag
      register_taxonomy('locations','post',array(
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'labels' => $labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'location' ),
      ));
    }
```

Any ideas? It's driving me mad!

Comment: [`get_the_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/) requires a post ID as the first parameter. I think you mean to use [`get_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two parameters of get_the_terms function. They are $post and $taxonomy. Unlike the other "get_the_xxxx" functions that you can skip the $post (post object or post ID) parameter inside the loop, you must add the post object or post ID to the first parameter.

I think you should write

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post, 'locations' );
```

Instead of

```
$terms = get_the_terms( 'locations' );
```

Documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/